# Javascript: Convert a text box number entry into a corresponding letter grade

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

So far this is what I have but I can't get it to display the result. I want to be able to enter a number such as "75", click the button, and then the bottom textbox to say "C" and so on with other numbers.
So far my code looks like this:

When I click "CLICK HERE" I don't want the answer to be alone, I want it to show up in the readonly textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function myFunction() {
        var score = document.getElementById("score").value;

        if (90 <= score) 
            {document.write ("A");}
        else if (80 <= score && score < 90) 
            {document.write ("B");}
        else if (70 <= score && score < 80) 
            {document.write ("C");}
        else if (60 <= score && score < 70) 
            {document.write ("D");}
        else 
            {document.write ("E");} 
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Grade % <input type="number" id="score" value=""><br>
    <p><button onclick="myFunction()">CLICK HERE</button></p>
    Letter Grade <input type="text" id="letter" readonly><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the result in the page or in the input#letter element?

Comment: You have an extra closing brace bracket.

Comment: @karthick I want the letter grade to show up in the input textbox which is readonly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wo3ywgpm/

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions and issues.

- Use `parseInt` to convert it to a number before comparison.
  var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").value, 10);
- It is a bad practice to use `document.write`
- Bind the event handlers using javascript and avoid inline event handlers for readability purposes.

```js
// Select the element and bind the click event to the button
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // convert to integer before comparision
  var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").value, 10);
  var letterInput = document.getElementById("letter");
  var letter = "E";

  if (90 <= score) {
    letter = "A";
  } else if (80 <= score && score < 90) {
    letter = "B";
  } else if (70 <= score && score < 80) {
    letter = "C";
  } else if (60 <= score && score < 70) {
    letter = "D";
  }

  letterInput.value = letter;
});
```

```html
Grade %
<input type="number" id="score" value="">
<br>

<p>
  <button id="btn">CLICK HERE</button>
</p>

Letter Grade
<input type="text" id="letter" readonly>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` outputs text in that spot. What you want to do is replace those with `document.getElementById('score').value = SOME_VAL` where `SOME_VAL` is your letter grade.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the input element and set the value in it. Not in the page. document.write's target is the whole html not the element. In order to show the result in the input element use document.getElementById("element") and set the value of that element by using .value()

```js
function myFunction() {
 var score = document.getElementById("score").value;
 if (90 <= score) {
  document.getElementById("letter").value = 'A';
 } else if (80 <= score && score < 90) {
  document.getElementById("letter").value = 'B';
 } else if (70 <= score && score < 80) {
  document.getElementById("letter").value = 'C';
 } else if (60 <= score && score < 70) {
  document.getElementById("letter").value = 'D';
 } else {
  document.getElementById("letter").value = 'E';
 }
}
```

```html
Grade % <input type="number" id="score" value=""><br>

<p><button onclick="myFunction()">CLICK HERE</button></p>

Letter Grade <input type="text" id="letter" readonly><br><br>
```